# Symfony, Doctrine, how do I load all the data in a join but also load the data row with columns that have no data?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I apologize if the question doesn't make any sense. So essentially I have 3 tables, table One, Two, and Three that are linked together. Table One is OneToMany relationship with table Two, and table Two has OneToMany Relationship with table Three.

The tables have the following columns:

One

```
id | package_no | weight | dimensions
```

Two

```
id | one_id | rack_no | part_no | batch_no
```

Three

```
id | two_id | datein | dateout
```

So only some of these data have a `dateout` from table Three since it is optional. When I list the data from table One and Two and Three, Doctrine is only distinctly listing the rows that have a `dateout`. I want it to list all the rows even when it doesn't have a `dateout`, and have that table cell as empty.

This is what I tried:

```
 $pkg = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Two')
        ->findInventoryByPkgno($packageNo);
```

I first tried by doing a query that grabs the data by `package_no` and it will give me the data from table One and Two, and then I did a for loop to grab each `two_id` to get the data from table Three.

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($pkg);$i++) {
        $twoid = $pkg[$i]['packageNo'];

        $getthree = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Three')
            ->findOneByTwoId($twoid);
    }
```

But then I realized when I output it to twig, it is just going to list only one result...

Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of findOneByTwoId($twoid) use findByTwoId($twoid);  That will give you an array.  Bur read what @Roberto wrote more carefully.  If you have your relations setup properly then there will be no need for the Bundle:Three query at all.  Loading the package will give you the batch as well as the date info.  Spend some tie looking at the relationship chapter in the Doctrine 2 manual.

Answer (score 0):

do you have configured the mapped/inversed in the entity ?

ONE:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Two",mappedBy="one",cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $twos;

 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->twos = new ArrayCollection();
 }  

public function getTwos()
{
    return $this->twos;
}
```

and two:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="One",inversedBy="twos")
 */
private $one;

public function getOne(){
  return $this->one;
}
```

and the controller yo can do:

```
$ones = $em->getRepository('Bundle:One')->findAll();
foreach($ones as $one){
 foreach($one->getTwos() as $two){
    //Access entity $two
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to list all the data in the repository but by an entity. For example in this case I want to find all by its Package #.